# Clear all displayed records from mysql on page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have display.php page and all records from mysql are being displayed on this page with help of while loop. There is a search box on top, now i want when i search particular id in search box then all the displayed records should be hidden and only particular id record should be displayed on screen against which i am searching for.

i tried to hide the the div using jquery but only 1 record hide, but i want to hide all old recorrds

```
 <?php
    //all data is displaying through this code
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($n))
    {
        echo "<div>Student Name</div>";
        echo "<div>".$row['studentName']."</div>";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['searchBtn']))
    {
        //here i want hide old data from page and then display searched data
        $id=$_POST["stdID"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM std_table Where studentID='$id'" ;
        $n=$connection->query($query);

        if ($n->num_rows > 0) 
        {
          while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($n))
          {
            echo "<div>Student Name</div>";
            echo "<div>".$row['studentName']."</div>";
          }
        }
 ?>
```

i tried to resolve this problem, but when I search id of specific data then a new row is created below the already displayed records, but i want clear the old data and want just display new data against the searched id

Comment: Please use prepared statements. Right now you're vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Well you are in code writting first a statement that tells that all should be printed and then you ask if there is an id and print it so you are getting what your logic is telling, you want to take that first part where you print all, and put it on an ELSE to the if of the second part, that way IF there is an id, only that is printend, if not, all is printed, also you are missing a "}" at the end to close the first IF (you put your else with the code after that mising "}")

Answer (score 0):

You are always printing all, and then you are asking if there is and id and printing. you want to use else for the print all part

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['searchBtn']))
{
    //here i want hide old data from page and then display searched data
    $id=$_POST["stdID"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM std_table Where studentID='$id'" ;
    $n=$connection->query($query);

    if ($n->num_rows > 0) 
    {
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($n))
      {
        echo "<div>Student Name</div>";
        echo "<div>".$row['studentName']."</div>";
      }
    }
}else{
         //all data is displaying through this code
         while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($n)){
             echo "<div>Student Name</div>";
             echo "<div>".$row['studentName']."</div>";
         }?>
```

Comment: the $query will display record for this SELECT * FROM std_table is only assigned if there is a Post of the search button the else is asigned to that if, so if there is no post the value of query will be the value i am assuming he previously added (he is not showing in the code, but you can see he prints all records so he must have a select * from stc_table; up there